# Can't login to the webpage via AFNetworking (Iphone)

Tags: ios, iphone, cookies, uiwebview, afnetworking-2

I want to log in to this webpage and see the logged version in my `UIWebView`, but my code doesn't work.

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username": @"myUsername", @"password": @"myPassword"};
    [manager POST:@"http://9gag.com/login" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
        NSData *data = (NSData*)responseObject;
        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithCString:[data bytes] encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *headerFields = operation.response.allHeaderFields;
        NSString *cookie = [headerFields valueForKey:@"Set-Cookie"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://9gag.com"]];
        [request addValue:cookie forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
        WebViewController *wvc = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithRequest:request];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:wvc animated:YES];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

What do you think I am doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What you are getting in response?

Comment: It would be easier to say that I don't get the loggedin version of the webpage in my webviewcontroller.

Comment: What are you talking about? If you are executing above code than you must be getting something either in responseObject or error. I am asking you that.

Comment: yeah i get responseobject with headers "cache-control", ",content-encoding", "content-type", "set-cookies" etc

Comment: everything works fine, but my webview, in which I load my request with cookies, doesn't show the logged in version of the website